# Is is possible to specify multiple return types for Javascript intellisense in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I have created an intellisense file for some custom objects that I have created and it is all working fine if the methods can only ever return a single type.

As an example to illustrate my question, if the intellisense file contains:

```
var Bob = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Bob"/>
    /// </signature>
}

var Fred = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Fred"/>
    /// </signature>
}

Bob.prototype.DoWhatBobDoes = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Bob"/>
    /// </signature>
}

Fred.prototype.DoWhatFredDoes = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Fred"/>
    /// </signature>
}
```

Then in Visual Studio I can do this, i.e. it knows that the DoWhatFredDoes() method returns a Fred object:

[image: intellisense]

However some of my methods can have multiple return types, for example the DoWhatFredDoes() method could return a Bob or a Fred object.  Is there anyway in the intellisense file to specify this?

I have tried modifying it to this, but it doesn't work:

```
var Bob = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Bob"/>
    /// </signature>
}

var Fred = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Fred"/>
    /// </signature>
}

Bob.prototype.DoWhatBobDoes = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Bob"/>
    /// </signature>
}

Fred.prototype.DoWhatFredDoes = function() {
    /// <signature>
    /// <returns type="Fred|Bob"/>
    /// </signature>
}
```

I've had a look at the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh542719.aspx and there is no mention of multiple return types so maybe it's just not possible?

Comment: A function signature can never differ by return type alone. I don't see how your function could ever return multiple types. The closest you can come to that is if `Fred` and `Bob` share a common ancestor type that the function is defined to return. But in that case it is still only returning a single type, the ancestor type.

Comment: @gmiley The function could return a different type if, for example, the method had a parameter that if set to 1 would return a Fred object, otherwise return a Bob object.

Comment: Yes, but that is the primary signature change, the parameters. You cannot have a function that only differs by return type: if you have `SomeFunction()` that returns a `string` then you cannot have `SomeFunction()` that returns an `int`, but you can have `SomeFunction(int)` that returns an `int`. `SomeFunction(int)` could then never return a `string` since it is already defined to return an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  What I meant was if the parameter was set to 1 it would return Fred, if it was set to 2 it would return Bob. So the function signature would be the same.  As I suspected, and you have confirmed, you can't have multiple return types for the same function signature. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function signature cannot differ by return type alone. For instance, if you have a function defined as `SomeFunction()` that returns the type `int`, you cannot also have `SomeFunction()` that returns the type `string`. However, if the function differs by number or type of parameters, each of those function definitions can have a different return type. For example: if `SomeFunction(int)` returns an `int`, you can also define `SomeFunction(string)` which can return a `string`, however once you define `SomeFunction(string)` to return a `string`, you cannot also define it to return an `int` as well.